# Angular Material 4 flex layout

Tags: angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Installed material flex layout in my project but i unable to see the file in @node_modules and its not rendering properly for flex layout css.

Below code i followed, please suggest any thing missing here.

**installed**

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout@latest --save
```

**imported app.components.ts**

```
import { ObservableMedia } from '@angular/flex-layout';
```

**imported in app.moduel.ts**

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,   
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
```

Node:
installed version

```
@angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.9
```

*for reference*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing seems to be missing. Pay attention to your Angular version - *"Deprecated support for Angular 2.4.x"*  https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

You should be able to find the lib here: node_modules/@angular/flex-layout. Here is some basic directive usage example. Hope it helps!

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
  <div fxFlex="33"></div>
  <div fxFlex="33"></div>
  <div fxFlex="33"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex layout works great with angular, all you need is here.
Please visit this link and follow documentation:

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

*---------Extra Note---------------*

*If you are using visual code there is also a plugin for angular flex layout which can be used for more fast coding.*